# Why does switchMap operator only emit the last value when used with a promise?

Tags: promise, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, switchmap

I have some trouble to understand this. When I use the switchMap operator with an Observable it emits all the values as expected:

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .do(console.log)
    .switchMap(i => Observable.of('*' + i))
    .do(console.log)
    .subscribe();
```

Results:

```
1
*1
2
*2
3
*3
4
*4
5
*5
```

But when I replace the the Observable by a Promise I get a different behaviour:

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .do(console.log)
    .switchMap(i => new Promise((resolve) => resolve('*' + i)))
    .do(console.log)
    .subscribe();
```

Results:

```
1
2
3
4
5
*5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as expected. The unexpected behaviors as you said is because `Observable.from` and `Observable.of` are always strictly synchronous while `new Promise` necessarily doesn't (I'm not sure about the specification so maybe that's what Promise has to do in all browsers).

Anyway you can force `Observable.from` emit asynchronously by passing the `async` Scheduler.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';

Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], async)
    .do(console.log)
    .switchMap(i => new Promise((resolve) => resolve('*' + i)))
    .do(console.log)
    .subscribe();
```

Now every emission is in a new frame just like `Promise` and the output is as you expected.

See live demo (open console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-gfeqsn?file=index.ts

Comment: This completely makes sense! But could you clarify why the fact of having emissions in separate frames behave this way? I would expect to have all emissions as output. (Or I probably don't understand the expected behaviour of switchMap.) Thanks. @martin

Comment: That's because `switchMap` receives `1` and subscribes to `new Promise()`. Then in the same frame it receives `2` and unsubscribes from the previous `Promise` and subscribes to the new one and so on. And only after `5` and its `Promise` the frame ends and JS evaluates another frame where only the last active `Promise` is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap), maybe it is what you are looking for.